# Invalid factor level when setting rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r

This is the a little confusing to me here are the steps I am taking:

Create a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(one=numeric(5), two=character(5))
```

This makes a dataframe with the columns "one" and "two" with 5 empty rows. Then I can try to assign a value to a row.

```
df[1,] <- list(1, "test")
```

This results in an error. If I do it with pure numeric values there is no issue. Also if I use list(1, "") that works as well.

List can handle different vector types and so can a dataframe so I am probably making a syntax mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for helping a new learner =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid converting to `factor` class, you can set the options to `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or specify it within the `data.frame`

```
 op <- options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 df[1,] <- list(1, "test")
 options(op)
 df
 #  one  two
 #1   1 test
 #2   0     
 #3   0     
 #4   0     
 #5   0
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you should prevent converting strings to factors when constructing your data frame.
Full code:

```
df <- data.frame(one=numeric(5), two=character(5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[1,] <- list(1, "test")
```

should work fine.

Comment: Strings are stored as `factor` which is essentially *integer*, where each distinct string is assigned a distinct value. The problem arises when you try to insert a *string* in a *factor* column, because of incompatible types.